# TableView how to filter certain cells from the table

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In a `UITableViewController` class that is responsible to populate a `TableView` with cells, I want to filter some of the cells but I can't figure out how I would do that.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return meals.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell

       let meal = meals[indexPath.row]
       cell.title.text = meal.name

       return cell
}
```

I have the attribute `meal.veg : Bool` and ideally, I want to populate the `TableView` only with meals that are `meal.veg == true`. What I am stuck with, is that I can't really understand how the `override func tableView()` does populate the table. I mean how is this function called? And how can I filter the cells.

Because the return type of the function is `UITableViewCell` and is not Optional, I have to return a cell, which doesn't allow the chance for cell filtering.

Comment: You need to do the filter on your array data source: `meals`. Something like `meals.filter({$0.veg == true})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem** - With `UITableView`, the method which is fired first is `numberOfRowsInSection` this will tell the TableView how many cell are there in the `TableView`, after getting the numbers the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will get fired which will used to design your `TableView`.

Now you are returning a count lets say 10 in `numberOfRowsInSection` out of which you just want to show 5 cell lets say those 5 are `meal.veg == true`, based on your filter meal.veg which is not possible as you need to return a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

**Solution** - To resolve it, before reloading your table view you need to filter your array and filter out those results which are having a value `meal.veg == true`, then you need to pass the count of your filtered array in `numberOfRowsInSection` and as per that filtered array you can design your cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example, with some extra suggestions :)

OK so let's say you've got a class, something like:

```
class Meal {
    var name: String
    var veg: Bool

    init(_ name: String, isVeg veg: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.veg = veg
    }
}
```

Then you have a load of meals in an array:

```
let carrots = Meal("Carrots", isVeg: true)
let steak = Meal("Steak & chips", isVeg: false)
let curry = Meal("Chicken korma", isVeg: false)
let sausage = Meal("Bangers and mash!", isVeg: false)
let salad = Meal("Spring asparagus salad", isVeg: true)

let meals = [carrots, steak, curry, sausage, salad]
```

What you want to do is filter those meals (based on whatever parameter you like).

```
var isFiltered = true
var filteredMeals = meals.filter { $0.veg }
```

Here you can see I've added a value (`isFiltered`) for whether you want to use the filter or not. (We'll see more why in a sec). Note also that the filteredMeals is in a separate array so that we don't lose our original data source, should we wish to remove or change the filter.

With your `tableView` you'd then set the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isFiltered ? filteredMeals.count : meals.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell

    let meal = isFiltered ? filteredMeals[indexPath.row] ? meals[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = meal.name

    return cell
}
```

So here you can see I'm making use of the `isFiltered` variable to determine whether I want to use the filtered results or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just filter the meals(outside of table view's datasource method) instead of cells and use the count of the filtered meals accordingly? Like:

```
let filteredMeals = meals.filter { $0.veg == true }
```